# Western Digital External 1TB HDD, possible to mount internally?

Tags: hard-drive

I have an external WD MyBook. it has USB, Firewire and e-sata connectors, but I would like to mount it internally in my desktop system instead for extra performance, and I'm also considered about how long it will last externally.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Has anyone done this with success? I would have to remove it from the existing external chasis, but before I mess around with this, I would like to know if its even possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[External enclosures](http://www.newegg.com/store/subcategory.aspx?subcategory=92&name=external-enclosures) are very simple animals. If you open it up, you'll see it's just a regular hard drive coupled to a very simple backplane that provides IDE/SATA to USB/Firewire translation.

So just open it up, take out the hard drive, and plug it into a regular slot. It's as simple as that. I have a few external cases that I routinely swap internal drives into and out of.

@Harry: I've never seen a drive in an external enclosure that's not a plain consumer-grade drive. They may not be top of the line, but you should still see a substantial gain over Firewire or USB2.

Comment: @JL: Just to note that external drives normally have slower rotation speed than disks intended for internal use. Check the specs, but the performance gain might not be as much as you would hope for.